# Download Objects from S3 Bucket using c#

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

Im trying to download object from S3 bucket facing below issue 
**The Security token included in the request is Invalid .**
Please check and correct where is the mistake.

Below is my code 
1. Get Temporary credentails:

```
main()    
{
    string path = "http://XXX.XXX.XXX./latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/EC2_WLMA_Permissions";

                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(path);
                request.Method = "GET";
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
                string result = string.Empty;
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    dynamic metaData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
                    _awsAccessKeyId = metaData.AccessKeyId;
                    _awsSecretAccessKey = metaData.SecretAccessKey;
                }
}
```

2. Create SessionAWSCredentials  instance:

   ```
   SessionAWSCredentials tempCredentials =
                    GetTemporaryCredentials(_awsAccessKeyId, _awsSecretAccessKey);
   ```

   //GetTemporaryCredentials method:

   ```
      private static SessionAWSCredentials GetTemporaryCredentials(
                       string accessKeyId, string secretAccessKeyId)
       {             

           AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient stsClient =
           new AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient(accessKeyId,
                                                    secretAccessKeyId);
           Console.WriteLine(stsClient.ToString());
           GetSessionTokenRequest getSessionTokenRequest =
                                            new GetSessionTokenRequest();

           getSessionTokenRequest.DurationSeconds = 7200; // seconds
           GetSessionTokenResponse sessionTokenResponse =
                         stsClient.GetSessionToken(getSessionTokenRequest);

           Console.WriteLine(sessionTokenResponse.ToString());
           Credentials credentials = sessionTokenResponse.Credentials;
           Console.WriteLine(credentials.ToString());

           SessionAWSCredentials sessionCredentials =
               new SessionAWSCredentials(credentials.AccessKeyId,
                                         credentials.SecretAccessKey,
                                         credentials.SessionToken);


           return sessionCredentials;
       }
   ```
3. Get files from `S3` using AmazonS3Client:

   ```
   using (IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(tempCredentials,RegionEndpoint.USEast1))                        
       {
                       GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest();
                       request.BucketName = "bucketName" + @"/" + "foldername";
                       request.Key = "Terms.docx";
                       GetObjectResponse response = client.GetObject(request);
                       response.WriteResponseStreamToFile("C:\\MyFile.docx");
       }
   ```

Comment: Is this all in one application?

Answer (score 33):

We do something a little simpler for interfacing with S3 (downloads and uploads)

It looks like you went the more complex approach. You should try just using the `TransferUtility` instead:

```
TransferUtility fileTransferUtility =
    new TransferUtility(
        new AmazonS3Client("ACCESS-KEY-ID", "SECRET-ACCESS-KEY", Amazon.RegionEndpoint.CACentral1));

// Note the 'fileName' is the 'key' of the object in S3 (which is usually just the file name)
fileTransferUtility.Download(filePath, "my-bucket-name", fileName);
```

---

**NOTE:** `TransferUtility.Download()` returns void because it downloads the file to the path specified in the `filePath` argument. This may be a little different than what you were expecting but you can still open a `FileStream` to that path afterwards and manipulate the file all you want. For example:

```
using (FileStream fileDownloaded = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    // Do stuff with our newly downloaded file
}
```

Comment: One thing to note here is that `filePath` needs to be **full path** of the file, otherwise you'll get error. It is very easy to miss for beginners.

Comment: How can you do this via a C# lambda (i.e. the file can't be downloaded) - why can't you work with filestreams directly from S3?

Answer (score 10):

```
Bucketname, Accesskey and secretkey, I took from web config. You could type manually.

 public void DownloadObject(string imagename)
    {
        RegionEndpoint bucketRegion = RegionEndpoint.USEast1;
        IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(bucketRegion);

        string accessKey = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSAccessKey"];
        string secretKey = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSSecretKey"];            
        AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey), Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
        string objectKey = "EMR" + "/" + imagename;
        //EMR is folder name of the image inside the bucket 
        GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest();
        request.BucketName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["bucketname"];      
        request.Key = objectKey;
        GetObjectResponse response = s3Client.GetObject(request);         
        response.WriteResponseStreamToFile("D:\\Test\\"+ imagename);

    }
```

//> D:\Test\ is local file path.

Answer (score 1):

Following is how I download it. I need to download only `.zip` files in this case. Restricting to only required file types (.zip in my case), helped me to avoid errors related to `(416) Requested Range Not Satisfiable`

```
    public static class MyAWS_S3_Helper
    {
        static string _S3Key = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["S3BucketKey"].ConnectionString;
        static string _S3SecretKey = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["S3BucketSecretKey"].ConnectionString;

        public static void S3Download(string bucketName, string _ObjectKey, string downloadPath)
        {
            IAmazonS3 _client = new AmazonS3Client(_S3Key, _S3SecretKey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
            TransferUtility fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(_client);
            fileTransferUtility.Download(downloadPath + "\\" + _ObjectKey, bucketName, _ObjectKey);
            _client.Dispose();
        }

        public static async Task AsyncDownload(string bucketName, string downloadPath, string requiredSunFolder)
        {
            var bucketRegion = RegionEndpoint.USEast1; //Change it
            var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(_S3Key, _S3SecretKey);
            var client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, bucketRegion);

            var request = new ListObjectsV2Request
            {
                BucketName = bucketName,
                MaxKeys = 1000
            };

            var response = await client.ListObjectsV2Async(request);
            var utility = new TransferUtility(client);

            foreach (var obj in response.S3Objects)
            {
                string currentKey = obj.Key;
                double sizeCheck = Convert.ToDouble(obj.Size);
                int fileNameLength = currentKey.Length;
                Console.WriteLine(currentKey + "---" + fileNameLength.ToString());

                if (currentKey.Contains(requiredSunFolder))
                {
                    if (currentKey.Contains(".zip")) //This helps to avoid errors related to (416) Requested Range Not Satisfiable
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            S3Download(bucketName, currentKey, downloadPath);
                        }
                        catch (Exception exTest)
                        {
                            string messageTest = currentKey + "-" + exTest;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Here is how it is called

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string downloadPath = @"C:\SourceFiles\TestDownload";
            Task  awsTask = MyAWS_S3_Helper.AsyncDownload("my-files", downloadPath, "mysubfolder");
            awsTask.Wait();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have done to download the files from S3 bucket,

```
var AwsImportFilePathParcel = "TEST/TEMP"

IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(AwsAccessKey,AwsSecretKey);
            
S3DirectoryInfo info = new S3DirectoryInfo(client, S3BucketName, AwsImportFilePathParcel);
            
S3FileInfo[] s3Files = info.GetFiles(pattenForParcel);
```

now in s3Files, you have all the files which are on provided location, using for each you can save all files in to your system

```
foreach (var fileInfo in s3Files)
{

    var localPath = Path.Combine("C:\TEST\", fileInfo.Name);
    var file = fileInfo.CopyToLocal(localPath);
}
```